# Rails 3.2 before_destroy destroy children conditionally not firing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I've got the following three models:

```
class Tag < AR::Base
  has_many   :mention_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many   :mentions, through: :mention_tags

  before_destroy :destroy_mentions

  def destroy_mentions
    mentions.each do |mention|
      mention.destroy if mention.tags.count == 1
    end
  end
end

class MentionTag < AR::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :mention
end

class Mention < AR::Base
  has_many    :mention_tags
  has_many    :tags,         through: :mention_tags
end
```

It seems the `destroy_mentions` method isn't calling `.destroy` on mentions that have a tag count of 1 when that tag is being destroyed and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here's a passing spec:

```
describe 'mention with this and other tags' do
  before do
    @tag1 = Tag.create(text: 'whatever', conditional: 'yes')
    @tag2 = Tag.create(text: 'whatever2', conditional: 'yes')
    @mention = Mention.create(text: 'whatever', tags: [@tag1, @tag2])
  end

  it 'should not delete the mention when deleting the tag' do
    @tag1.destroy
    Mention.exists?(id: @mention.id).should be_true
  end
end
```

and this spec fails:

```
describe 'mention with only this tag' do
  before do
    @tag = Tag.create(text: 'whatever', conditional: 'yes')
    @mention = Mention.create(text: 'whatever', tags: [@tag])
  end

  it 'should delete the mention when deleting the tag' do
    @tag.destroy
    Mention.exists?(id: @mention.id).should be_false
  end
end
```

Comment: it seems commenting out the `depedent: :destroy` on the `Tag` model causes all specs to pass, but i want to get rid of all of those when a tag is deleted as a mention can have multiple tags and wont always be deleted.